# Diccionario con conteo de vocales en texto

Tags: python, diccionarios, contador, formato-condicional

Estoy intentando crear un script que genere un dicccionario con las vocales como claves y las veces que aparecen en la cadena de texto los valores.

Aunque al ejecutarlo si que funciona, en el diccionario creado, no aparecen sólo las vocales de dic_vocales como debe ser, sino que aparecen tanto las vocales como las consonantes que tiene la cadena de texto, y no sé que hacer para solucionarlo.

El código es el siguiente:

```
cadena_texto ="Hola,que tal"

def conteo_vocales(texto):
     
    texto = texto.lower()
    dic_vocales = {"a":0,"e":0,"i":0,"o":0,"u":0}
    for i in cadena_texto: 
        if i in dic_vocales.keys():
            dic_vocales[i] = dic_vocales[i] +1
            count= texto.count(i)
        else:
            dic_vocales[i] = 1
            
    return dic_vocales  

numero_vocales= conteo_vocales(cadena_texto)

print(help(conteo_vocales))
print(numero_vocales)
```

Comment: ¿No te sería mejor poner `dic_vocales = {"a": texto.count("a") +texto.count("á"),"e": texto.count("e") + texto.count("é"),"i": texto.count("i") +texto.count("í"),"o": texto.count("o") + texto.count("ó"),"u": texto.count("u") +texto.count("ú") + texto.count("ü") }`?

Comment: Como lo tienes hasta ahora, al recorrer el texto, cuando la letra `i` (sea vocal o consonante), no se encuentre en `dic_vocales`, este la agregará al diccionario: `dic_vocales[i] = 1` y, si en las próximas iteraciones aparece esa letra, entrará a `if i in dic_vocales.keys():`. Por eso te agrega las consonantes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está en que si no encuentras la letra en el diccionario, le generas una entrada inicializada en 1.

```
   if i in dic_vocales.keys():
        dic_vocales[i] = dic_vocales[i] +1
        count= texto.count(i) # La variable count no es usada ...
    else:                     # Aqui agregas las no-vocales.
        dic_vocales[i] = 1    # Eliminar esto.
```

Una solución:

```
def conteo_vocales(texto):
    dic = dict(a=0, e=0, i=0, o=0, u=0)
    for letra in texto.lower():
        if letra in dic:
            dic[letra] += 1
    return dic
```

Como se trata un pequeño número de letras a contar, inicializamos explícitamente un diccionario indexado por vocal, con valor cero para cada llave.

Luego queda recorrer las letras del texto, que ponemos en minúsculas para uniformar las letras.

Como el diccionario ya contiene todas las vocales, sólo necesito preguntar si la letra actual es una llave en el diccionario, por tanto, es una vocal.

Al final sólo queda retornar el diccionario.

**Prueba**

```
texto = "AEIOUaeiou"
print(texto, conteo_vocales(texto))
texto = "La mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta"
print(texto, conteo_vocales(texto))
```

produce

```
AEIOUaeiou {'a': 2, 'e': 2, 'i': 2, 'o': 2, 'u': 2}
La mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta {'a': 7, 'e': 2, 'i': 2, 'o': 2, 'u': 2}
```

Comment: Conseguí que funcionara gracias a tu solución, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Como ya han comentado, tienes el error en el `else` que no está limitado sólo a las vocales.

La forma más rápida de contar vocales sería:

```py
def conteo_vocales(sentencia: str):
    return {vocal: sentencia.count(vocal) for vocal in "aeiou"}
```

Si la frase no es muy larga, el conteo es suficientemente rápido para que compense tener que hacerlo 5 veces, una por vocal. Para textos largos, puede ser mejor hacer un filtrado previo:

```py
def conteo_vocales(sentencia: str):
    vocales = [letra for letra in sentencia if letra in "aeiou"]
    return {vocal: vocales.count(vocal) for vocal in "aeiou"}
```

Para considerar la posibilidad de tener vocales mayúsculas y minúsculas, se puede convertir la sentencia a minúsculas usando `.casefold()` (recomendado cuando se hacen comparaciones, aunque también se puede usar `lower` en este caso):

```py
def conteo_vocales(sentencia: str):
    vocales = [letra for letra in sentencia.casefold() if letra in "aeiou"]
    return {vocal: vocales.count(vocal) for vocal in "aeiou"}
```

Si el texto es tan enorme que no nos cabe en memoria, entonces es mejor cambiar de estrategia y emplear iterables, sin copias intermedias:

```py
def conteo_vocales(sentencia):
    conteo = {vocal: 0 for vocal in "aeiou"}
    vocales = (letra.casefold() for letra in sentencia if letra in "AEIOUaeiou")
    for vocal in vocales:
        conteo[vocal] += 1
    return conteo
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!